# How do I use parameters in a constructor in a rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I trying to learn tdd using RSpec. I took this example from a cheat sheet I found online and am a bit confused as to how I would implement it. To add MovieList.new is automatic but how would I go about adding a parameter when it is already handled with ActiveRecord. And then to add the 'forward' method as well.

```
describe "forward" do
  it "should jump to a next movie" do
    next_movie = MovieList.new(2).forward
    next_movie.track_number.should == 2
  end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to implement here? You haven't explained your problem very well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a test for a MovieList class, create a class called MovieList.

Then in your constructor for that class, make sure it takes in a parameter called track_number, in your test that's the 2.

Then create a method called forward to do whatever you need it to do?

Here's a good example of where I'm going with this:
http://rspec.info/

This may sound ambiguous, but so was the question.

---

**EDIT:**
This is a rough idea of how to create a new MovieList class and initialize it with a parameter called track_number.

```
def MovieList
  attr_accessor :track_number

  def initialize(track_number)
    @track_number = track_number
  end

  # You can define all your class methods below, you 
  # can start with forward.

  def forward
    # do something...
  end 

end
```

Comment: My confusion is that I thought ActiveRecord already had the constructor for the model.

Comment: I see, you can do something like I added in the edit up above.

I don't believe ActiveRecord can read your mind this way :)

But attr_accessor will make your life easier because it creates the getters and setters for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, just curious is it necessary to say def initialize (track_number, attributes = {})
  super( attributes ) ... end

Comment: umm that looks like you're trying to inherit from a parent class? It's not necessary, but if you need to do it, read up on it here: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_inheritance.html

Comment: parent class may have initialization logic (I believe, ActiveRecord classes have) and if you are not sure, then call super inside child constructor or you can leave your object in not initialized state and it will fail later

Answer (score 1):

```
movie = Movie.new(:track_number => 2)
movie.forward
```

I am not sure what forward does in your example because you seem to be initializing track_number to 2 then calling forward. I would have expected track_number to increment but your test is checking to see if it's 2 still.

Note, I don't believe you need to change your constructor to take the parameter as long as you pass it in as a hash (the single member hash is implied in my example)...can someone verify or refute this last assertion?